# php spreadsheet - getting the value instead of the formula

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I'm trying to upload a spreadsheet using phpspreadsheet.

I simply want to copy the values of each cell I see when I open the spreadsheet in open office, into the database

The problem is in one of the columns, the value is calculated and despite reading the phpspreadsheet documentation, I can't find out how to do this.

The value I can see if I open the spreadsheet with Open Office would be just a float like 9.12, but in the input bar where you'd type a formula, the value is:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'file:///Folder for Tenders & Information required/October19/All Group Pricing Oct 2019 working.xlsx'#$'PI''s'.$A$1:$Y$1048576,25,0)
```

If I run this code:

```
$reader = IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName2);

$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$value = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('F2')->getCalculatedValue();
echo $value;
```

That produces the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Exception: PI!F2 -> Formula Error:
```

If I change getCalculatedValue() to getValue()

I get:

```
    =VLOOKUP(A2,'[1]PI''s'!$A:$Y,25,FALSE)
```

How on earth do I just get the value that I can see when I open the spreadsheet in Open Office?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('F2')->getOldCalculatedValue()
```

But be careful that there is no guarantee that this value is correct, or even exist at all. It all depends on how the file was written.

Comment: Not sure what "getOldCalculatedValue()" is but "getCalculatedValue()" does what the OP requests

Comment: Incorrect. The OP does **not** want to calculate the value on the fly. Because the formula will fail. Instead the OP want to get the value that was calculated when the file was written, by another software. His use-case is uncommon and so requires the use of the less-common `getOldCalculatedValue()`.

For other people, with the most common use-case of calculating the value on the fly based on the current formula, then use the most common `getCalculatedValue()`.